# Condition with logical operator in the for loop

Tags: c, for-loop, conditional-statements

I wrote program in C for finding prime numbers by Sieve of Eratosthene (it's an exercise 6-8 in Kochan, Programming in C 4th edition). It's work just fine.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int prime[151], i, j;

    for(i = 2; i < 151; ++i)
        prime[i] = i;
    for(i = 2; i <= 150; ++i) 
        if(prime[i])
            for(j = i+i; j <= 150; j += i)
                prime[j] = 0;
    for(i = 2; i < 150; ++i)
        if(prime[i])
            printf("%i ", prime[i]);
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

But before I reach that form of code I try that for loop:

```
for(i = 2; prime[i] && i < 150; ++i)
```

That form save place by drop if statement and in my opinion need to work in the same way like first variant. But it stop after number 3!
Can anyone explain me why that condition in for loop work that way?

P.S. Yep, I know that algorithm of this program is not best.

Comment: Side note: you may as well change `prime[i] = i` to `prime[i] = 1` and `printf("%i ", prime[i])` to `printf("%i ", i)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, they are not the same:

- The original loop skips all non-prime numbers and keeps going.
- The proposed replacement terminates as soon as it encounters the first non-prime number (since `prime[i]` will become `false`, the loop will stop).

Comment: Now I see it. Need to be more attentive. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The middle part of a `for` loop, is like a `while`, not like an `if`. So as soon as you find and index where `prime[i]` is `0`, the loop will terminate.